# ThenInclude for Explicit Loading in Entity Framework core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I know I can go one step deeper to load related data using `ThenInclude` in Eager Loading like below example

```
//Eager Loading
var publisher = await _context.Publishers
                              .Include(pub => pub.Books)
                                  .ThenInclude(book => book.Sales)
                              .Include(pub => pub.Users)
                              .Where(pub => pub.PubId == id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

How can I write the same query in Explicit Loading? How do I load data for `Sales` without looping through books in below case?

```
//Explicit Loading
var publisher = await _context.Publishers
                              .SingleAsync(pub => pub.PubId == id);

_context.Entry(publisher)
        .Collection(pub => pub.Books)
        .Load();
                 
_context.Entry(publisher)
        .Collection(pub => pub.Users)                
        .Load();
```

Comment: Loop through each of the books and call Load on each of their Sales collections?

Comment: Ehm, alright.  Why are you averse to writing a loop?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thanks for your comment. Is there any way I can do it without looping through "Books". My questions does miss the whole purpose of having explicit loading though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry.query?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_NavigationEntry_Query) method is your friend.

It's partially explained in the [Querying related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#querying-related-entities) subsection of [Explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) documentation:

> You can also get a LINQ query that represents the contents of a navigation property.
>
> This allows you to do things such as running an aggregate operator over the related entities without loading them into memory.
>
> Example...
>
> You can also filter which related entities are loaded into memory.
>
> Example...

What they forgot to mention is that you can use it also for `Include` / `ThenInclude` related data of the explicitly loading data.

e.g.

```
_context.Entry(publisher)
    .Collection(pub => pub.Books)
    .Query() // <--
    .Include(book => book.Sales) // <--
    .Load();
```