# Entity Framework Core automatically recursively including collection for each entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have four models auto generated by Entity Framework Core (2.1.4) (using scaffold) that are related between themselves.

```
public partial class Run
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RunCarId { get; set; }
    public int RunExtraInfoId { get; set; }
    ...
    public RunExtraInfo RunExtraInfo{ get; set; }
    public RunCar RunCar{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Weighing> Weighings{ get; set; }
}

public partial class RunExtraInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<CorridaCt> Runs { get; set; }
}

public partial class RunCar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Run Run{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Weighing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RunId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Run Run{ get; set; }
}
```

But whenever I include all info I need on `Run`, all other relations are loaded to the entities, making it very recursive.

Example:

```cs
var runs = ContextSQL.Runs
                     .Include(c => c.RunExtraInfo)
                     .Include(c => c.RunCar)
                     .Include(c => c.Weighings)
                     .ToList();
return runs;
```

Generates:

```json
[
  {
    id: 0,
    ...
    runExtraInfo: {
      id: 0,
      ...
      runs: [
        {
          id: 0,
          runExtraInfo: {id: 0 runs: [...]},
          runCar: {id: 0, runs: [...]}
        }
      ]
    },
    runcar: {
      id: 0,
      runs: [
        {id: 0, runExtraInfo: [...], runs: [...]}
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I thought entity was supposed to include the relations only if we included them explicitly with `Include()`, am I wrong?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: An option is to use the attribute `[Script Ignore]` on places where you want to prevent recursion.

Comment: Shortly, you cannot stop EF Core doing that because it is by design. If you have serialization issues, use separated classes or serialization options/attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid it, you need to use *explicit loading* as described here [Explicit Loading in Entity Framework core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382491/theninclude-for-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework-core).

Or you need to return only the fields you need, instead of the database models:

```cs
var runs = ContextSQL.Runs
    .Include(c => c.RunExtraInfo)
    .Include(c => c.RunCar)
    .Include(c => c.Weighings)
    .Select(c => new { c.Id, c.RunExtraInfo, c.RunCar, c.Weighings })
    .ToList();
return runs;
```

Or instead of using an anonymous object, you can use DTO's that contains only the data you want (where you remove the fields and circular references you don't want):

```cs
var runs = ContextSQL.Runs
    .Include(c => c.RunExtraInfo)
    .Include(c => c.RunCar)
    .Include(c => c.Weighings)
    .Select(c => new RunDTO(c))
    .ToList();
return runs;
```

See (extern microsoft link) [Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).

As mentioned in the comments of your question, you can also use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, for fields you don't want converted to Json, but you may prefer to use DTO's instead.

Comment: I went with the DTO option, works like a charm, thanks.